# Facebook Flow. Declare possible values for string property

Tags: facebook, types, flowtype, flow-typed

I wonder if I can declare `type` prop like explained in square brackets:

```
type AxiosSUCCESS = {
  +type: [string value with 'SUCCESS' suffix],
  +payload: Object,
}

type AxiosFAILURE = {
  +type: [string value with 'FAILURE' suffix],
  +payload: Object,
}
```

I'm not sure if it's going to help flow in type checking, but at least will help a developer in understanding.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can`t. Maybe you would use a literal typing for it?
For example:

```
type AxiosSUCCESS = {
  +prefix: "SUCCESS",
  +type: string,
  +payload: {},
}
```

[More about literal typing](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/literals/)